# Опасно ли модифицировать JSONField не копируя его значение?

Tags: python, django

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    some_headers = models.JSONField()

    def _modifying_method(self):
        """Этот метод не вызывает save() после вызова pop,
        а соответственно значение не отредактируется на уровне объекта базы."""
        self.some_headers.pop("required_header")
        
        # Другие действия
        ...
   
    def calling_method(self):
        """Метод, вызывающий модифицирующий метод. Он так же не вызывает метод save()"""
        self._modifying_method()

        # Другие действия
        ...
```

Может ли отсутствие вызова метода save() служить гарантом того, что ключ в значении не исчезнет из базы и не произойдет ошибка KeyError во время следующего вызова? Нужно ли страховать код, руководствуясь словами "вдруг где-то всплывет вызов метода save(), о котором внутри методов модификации неизвестно"?

Comment: Как минимум, вы уже допустили ошибку, поместив в default мутабельный объект, который будет общим для всех создаваемых экземпляров ExampleModel до перезагрузки данных из базы. А так вроде бы база не должна трогаться без вызова метода save (а уж вызывается ли метод save — это вам в вашем коде виднее)

Comment: Писал чисто для примера. Даже об этом как-то не задумывался. Отредактировал вопрос. Вынесите это в ответ, пожалуйста.